# Missing office types on sharepoint online document library after adding content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

On an out of the box sharepoint online site i can find on the document library under the "New" button the most common office documents like word, excel, powerpoint and so on.
but as soon a i add an additional content type to the library. I can find the the created content type, for example the picture, but only word document and the other office tyoe like excel and pp are gone. After i remove the picture content type all type of office files a showing up again.

Why is that, and how i can bring back the excel an other office types on the new button.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/192058

> As it turns out, these "content types" comes from Office Online Server
>   (formerly knows as, Office WebApps Server). The only way to change
>   them is by adding custom content types. That goes from reordering as
>   well.
>
> > If you only have the default document content type then the new button
> >     will default to the 4 basic documents that can be created in Office
> >     Online server. If you add custom content types then the assumption is
> >     that each custom content type has a custom template associated with
> >     it. So then the New button will default to showing you the different
> >     document templates associated with each content type. This is all by
> >     design,
>
> - Paul Stork on O365 Network